# Silverlight : During uploading files to a URL, how to bypass the in-browser trusted application restriction?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, trusted

I have build a **Silverlight 5** application that allows users to drag and drop an item onto a selected area and upload them to a particular URL. Its an HTML page that references the **xap** file (that contains the Silverlight code) inside a div through the **object** tag. The purpose is that when the user drags an element into that div, the element should be uploaded to the server specified.

The problem is that for uploading the dragged item, I need to call **FileInfo**'s **getFullName()** method and it requires the user to be **trusted**. Since the Silverlight application will run inside the div of the HTML page, I am assuming that its a case of **in-browser** access, and according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article, it would *require a change in the end user's IE settings*. Asking the user to change his registry keys for uploading files is obviously not an option.

Is there any way out of the situation (that is, if I have understood the situation correctly) ?

Comment: Why do you need to call `FileInfo.getFullName()`?

Comment: So that I can upload the file to the server. Any other way to know the full path of the file that the user has dragged that doesn't require 'trusted' status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `FileInfo.getFullName()` to be able to upload the file to the server. Instead, you call the `FileInfo.OpenRead()` method, which returns a stream that reads the file's data.

An example of using drag-and-drop with user-supplied files can be found [here](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/11/26/silverlight-4-s-new-drag-and-drop-support.aspx).